# How can I get a list with absolute paths, but with a specific name rule? (batch script)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

i want to create a txt file, containing absolute paths for my robocopy backup. However, i only want to backup folders which have specific names in it.

This would be my source folder:

```
\\\fileserver\Projects
```

which contains folders like

```
20090-Miller-Georg
20094-Johnson-Susan
20097-Miller-Sarah
20125-Olston-John
20130-Johnson-Alex
....
```

Now here comes the tricky part: Let's say, i only want to list folders which contain e.g. Miller and Johnson, so my list would be something like this:

```
\\\fileserver\Projects\20090-Miller-Georg
\\\fileserver\Projects\20094-Johnson-Susan
\\\fileserver\Projects\20097-Miller-Sarah
\\\fileserver\Projects\20130-Johnson-Alex
...
```

In a batch script, `dir` does not enable this kind of sorting. Is there another way?

Comment: Did you try this. `dir /ad /b *-miller-* *-johnson-*`

Comment: @Squashman if i try your code, i get the error message "file not found"

Comment: @Compo: I tried your code, but the script copies everything, like *-olston-* etc.

Comment: @Henry, just retested the `DIR` command I gave you with your 5 directories and it definitely output 4 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can put in the .bat file script. It will produce UNC paths.

```
SET "BASEDIR=\\fileserver\Projects"

powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "%BASEDIR%" |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
            "if ($_.Name -cmatch '-Miller-|-Johnson-') {" ^
                "$_.FullName" ^
            "}" ^
        "}"
```

Of course, this is less cryptic when using PowerShell directly.

```
$basedir = '\\fileserver\Projects'

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $basedir |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Name -match '-Miller-|-Johnson-') {
            $_.FullName
        }
    }
```